# JavaScript algorithm question: get the find the contiguous subarray which has the largest sum from an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The question originates from this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/

But instead of returning the largest sum, I want to return the subarray that has the largest sum. For example, `[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]`, the largest sum is `6` as in `[4,-1,2,1]` . Here I want to return `[4,-1,2,1]` not `6` the number.

Here is my attempt:

```js
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let max = -Infinity
    let sum = 0
    const results = []
    for(const num of nums) {
        results.push(num)
        sum += num
        max = Math.max(sum, max)
        if(sum < 0) {
            sum = 0
            results.length = 0
        }
    }
    
    return results
};

maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4])
```

However it returns an incorrect answer - `[ 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 ]`. I found it really hard to implement this since it is hard to determine whether or not we should keep adding the subsequent item in the `results` array.

Wondering if anyone would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-maximum-subarray#kadane-algorithm), by using `Kadane’s algorithm` and maintain indices whenever we get the maximum sum.

```js
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    var max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
    var startIndex = -1;
    var endIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > max_ending_here + nums[i]) {
            startIndex = i;
            max_ending_here = nums[i];
        } else
            max_ending_here = max_ending_here + nums[i];
 
        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here) {
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
            endIndex = i;
        }
    }
    
    return nums.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
};

console.log(maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]))
```

Thanks [baeldung's blog.](https://www.baeldung.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) shows how to maintain indices whenever we get the maximum sum.

No JS, so I copy Java code here:

```
 static void maxSubArraySum(int a[], int size) 
    { 
        int max_so_far = Integer.MIN_VALUE, 
        max_ending_here = 0,start = 0, 
        end = 0, s = 0; 
  
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  
        { 
            max_ending_here += a[i]; 
  
            if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)  
            { 
                max_so_far = max_ending_here; 
                start = s; 
                end = i; 
            } 
  
            if (max_ending_here < 0)  
            { 
                max_ending_here = 0; 
                s = i + 1; 
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("Maximum contiguous sum is " 
                           + max_so_far); 
        System.out.println("Starting index " + start); 
        System.out.println("Ending index " + end); 
    }
```